# Can I force Google Feedfetcher to delete my feed and start over?

Tags: google-search-console, feeds

I royally screwed up my Atom feed yesterday by messing around with the `id` tags and now Google Reader is showing many duplicates of the posts. Is there any way I can tell it to start from scratch, now that I have fixed the `id` tag-structure?

The feed is at http://eseidel.org/atom.xml in case that helps..

Comment: Google Reader is going away, this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a feed you've submitted to Google webmaster tools? If so delete the feed and re-submit then wait for Google to update it's feed

Answer (score 0):

If your feed is provided by a blog or site hosting service, please work directly with that and change it with the new Atom feed.

If your feed is publicly available, then configure your site to serve a 404, 410, or other error status message to user-agent Feedfetcher-Google.